# Correct way to cite Stack Exchange Data Dump

Tags: support, etiquette, citation

I'm writing a paper in which I use the data dump from Stack Exchange, specifically Stack Overflow's data. How I should cite it?

Answer (score 2):

If your paper is statistical or based on an aggregate of data compiled from the data dump, you should give attribution to the original site that generated the content and the location of the data dump itself.

If you are quoting specific posts (i.e. reusing content posted by users), your attribution should go to the original author by referencing the original post on that site.

See

[**Attribution Required**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) and

[**Defending Attribution Required**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/) for reference.